# Cant find Wordpress Minimalist stylesheeet to change Span showing taxes

Tags: wordpress

I Dont want this Span saying Taxes are included in the sale of this product, because this is an un-taxable product. My plan is just to change the color of text to hide it, but I cant seem to find the right area to change it.

Im using WordPress minimalist[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to apply `!important;`

Comment: but where is my question?

Comment: Are you saying, you have applied CSS and it is not applying ? Just change the color on browser to check whether it is applying or not

Comment: I dont know how to FIND the right stylesheet to change " .payment"

Comment: Dont change in core CSS files, Do you have your custom style sheet?

Comment: no, should I create one, and will that one override the rest?

Comment: If you have a style sheet you can write your own CSS, by defining class names and override core css, You dont need to override all CSS, Just the required attribute  `.sidebar .payment-due-label__taxes`

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below to achieve what you want:

1. If you do not already have a child theme, create one with the name
   `YourThemeName-child` in `wp-content/themes`. Replace `YourThemeName`
   with the name of your theme.
2. Copy the CSS style from your main theme to your child theme.
3. Find the class of the element you want to hide by:
   In Chrome: Right click on the element you want to hide and click on Inspect Element. From the console on the right, copy the CSS class of the element.

In your child theme CSS (the one that you copied from the main theme) add this code:

```
.element-class {
color: #ffffff;
}
/* Use !important if changes do not show. Refrain from using !important unless absolutely necessary */
```

Or if you want to not display it completely:

```
.element-class {
display: none;
}
/* Use !important if changes do not show. Refrain from using !important unless absolutely necessary */
```

To answer your question in the comments, yes, creating a new CSS file in child theme will override the main theme CSS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I created the "-child" as seen in the 2nd picture above. It did not work. I believe it didnt work bc ".payment-due-label__taxes" is not localed in the asset/theme.scss file that i copied. I understand wordpress compile and translates the file into 1 master scss or css. but I dont know how to find .payment-due-label__taxes.

Comment: @mattnapper Could you share with me the names of the files in your main theme?

Comment: I added a picture of all my files, I've also found this line comes from a CDN from cdn.shopify.com/app/services/5972295731/assets/16752312371/checkout_stylesheet/v2-ltr-edge-7e299543fd543da263f8150b158a81d5-7636022388655706894/oldie....How can i override this code, and in what file